# advance join in laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, query-builder

I have a `user` table like this

```
+----+------------+-----------+---------+
| id | first_name | last_name | address |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+
| 1  |     x      |     y     |    z    |
| 2  |     a      |     b     |    c    |
| 3  |     p      |     q     |    r    |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+
```

and a `transfer` table like this

```
+----+--------------+------------+--------+
| id | from_user_id | to_user_id | amount |
+----+--------------+------------+--------+
| 1  |      1       |     2      |   20   |
| 2  |      2       |     1      |   10   |
| 3  |      3       |     2      |   10   |
+----+--------------+------------+--------+
```

Now I can use join query like this

```
 $transfer = DB::table('users')
            ->join('transfers', function($join) {
                $join->on('users.id', '=', 'transfers.from_user_id');
            })
            ->select('users.first_name','users.last_name', 'transfers.amount', 'transfers.date')
            ->get();
```

but doing this will ony give me the `first_name` and `last_name` corresponding to  `from_user_id` . But i also want the corresponding `first_name` and `last_name` respective to `to_user_id`. How can I get them?

my desired output table

```
+---------+---------+--------+
| sent_by | sent_to | amount |
+---------+---------+--------+
|   xy    |   ab    |   20   |
|   ab    |   xy    |   10   |
|   pq    |   ab    |   10   |
+---------+---------+--------+
```

Here is the MySQL query needed to generate the above table.  As you can see, it requires 2 inner joins:

```
SELECT CONCAT(u1.first_name, u1.last_name), CONCAT(u2.first_name, u2.last_name), t.amount
FROM transfer t INNER JOIN user u1
ON t.from_user_id = u1.id
INNER JOIN user u2
ON t.to_user_id = u2.id
```

Comment: You should show us the desired output table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen see the updated question

Comment: The easiest way for you to tackle this issue is to create a view in MySQL and then a Laravel read-only model that just reads from the view. That way you can avoid the whole shenanigans in regards to query builder, your code will be simpler (smaller) and querying views is a bit quicker than joining tables as you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt at a solution for your Laravel query:

```
$transfer = DB::table('transfer')
                     ->join('user as u1', 'transfer.from_user_id', '=', 'u1.id')
                     ->join('user as u2', 'transfer.to_user_id', '=', 'u2.id')
                     ->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(u1.first_name, u1.last_name) AS sent_by'), 
                              DB::raw('CONCAT(u2.first_name, u2.last_name) AS sent_to'),
                              'transfer.amount as amount')
                     ->get();
```

The trick is knowing how to include an alias for the double join from `transfer` to the `user` table, as well as using `DB::raw()` to access the MySQL `CONCAT` function.

Answer (score 2):

use aliases on your join tables.
Hope that helps.

```
$transfer = DB::table('transfers')
    ->join('users as senders', function($join) {
        $join->on('transfers.from_user_id', '=', 'senders.id');
    })
    ->join('users as receivers', function($join) {
        $join->on('transfers.to_user_id', '=', 'receivers.id');
    })
    ->select('senders.first_name','senders.last_name', 'receivers.first_name','receivers.last_name', 'transfers.amount', 'transfers.date')
    ->get();
```

Comment: well, that didn't help. I think you didn't understand my issue

Comment: I understood you want to get both info about the sender and the receiver of the transfert from a single query using Query Builder, don't you? // Edit: sorry you are right, I understand well but provided a wrong query, I correct it now ;)